# delete memory safely in destructor

Tags: c++, memory

I have the following code:

```
CCOLFile *pCOLFile = CCOLManager::getInstance()->parseFile(strCOLPath);
// ...
pCOLFile->unload();
delete pCOLFile;
```

Memory is allocated by the parseFile() function and stored in a std::vector in the pCOLFile object.
Can I move my code from the unload() method to the CCOLFile destructor to safely delete the allocated memory?

I'm guessing destructors maybe were even designed for this?

The goal is to iterate around a std::vector and use delete on each value.

Here's my CCOLFile struct:

```
struct CCOLFile
{
    std::string                     m_strFilePath;
    std::vector<CCOLEntry*>         m_vecEntries;
};
```

And here's the current unload() method:

```
void                CCOLFile::unload(void)
{
    for (auto pCOLEntry : m_vecEntries)
    {
        delete pCOLEntry;
    }
    m_vecEntries.clear();
}
```

Comment: Consider `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CCOLEntry>>`.  Not only can you do the deallocation in the destructor instead of needing a special `unload()` function, you can have the required logic written for you by the compiler, just by choosing to use a smart pointer instead of a bare pointer.

Comment: `CCOLManager::parseFile` ought to return a `unique_ptr` as well.

Comment: *"The goal is to iterate around a std::vector and use delete on each value."*  If you instead let the vector itself destroy the objects you have a much simpler situation. Ben V shows one possible way. Another way is to let the vector own the objects

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So just to confirm, if I use a smart pointer, I can use the unload() code inside the destructor? And If I use a bare pointer, I can't use the unload() code in the destructor? Also how would I go about letting the vector own the objects? What would the deletion process be for that?

Comment: No. If you use `unique_ptr`, you don't need a destructor or an `unload` function.

Comment: I've decided to look into using smart pointers in the future, this leaves 1 question. Can I move the code from CCOLFile::unload to the CCOLFile destructor, whilst not using smart pointers anywhere, and still using delete on the pCOLEntry, and the objects stored in the m_vecEntries std::vector will all safely get deleted?

Answer (score -1):

If you declare `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CColEntry>> m_vecEntries` then you don't need an `unload` method; instead, in the destructor, just do `delete m_vecEntries`.  The `vector` will clear its entries, and because they are `unique_ptr`'s, they will delete themselves.

Thus `unload()` is reduced to one line in the destructor.

Comment: "_Thus unload() is reduced to one line in the destructor_" -- ITYM the OP will neither need an `unload` function nor need to implement a destructor; the one auto-generated by the compiler would be sufficient.

Comment: Also, if `m_vecEntries` is a `std::vector`, then he should _not_ call `delete` on it.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I did mean that.  My second sentence was not intended as code (it should not have been edited -- a word was lost); I meant that the _auto-generated_ destructor would delete all the memory necessary.